# Sector progress bar cocos2d, iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to know how can I implement the sector progress bar in cocos2d-iphone? By sector animation I mean the following:

1) I have two circles. Smaller is inside the larger one, so there is some space between them;
2) Let's say that this space is divided by 5 equal segements
3) if user touches the screen then next segment is filled with the color

Comment: Take a look at CCProgressTimer modes.

Comment: May be, I didn't properly understand the class CCProgressTimer, but it couldn't do what is described in the following article: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/16779